# how to monitor who change the data inside the database mysql

Tags: java, mysql, triggers

What I want to achieve is to determine who change the data inside my database table, What I am doing right now is that I created a MySQL trigger that will record the current USER()  logged in, but I found a dead end with this since I have multiple users that I want to keep track to, and mysql trigger only allows 1 definer per trigger and I can only have 1 trigger per event which is cannot satisfy my current requirement where I need to keep track of all the users, meaning I need to know which one of them changed anything inside the database. Is there anyway for me to achieve this using mysql trigger? or another by pass option?

Comment: are you using hibernate or pure jdbc? I think all you need is audit trail.

Comment: @BilboBaggins i'm not sure what hibernate is but im using jdbc.

Comment: ok I can think of one strategy, create audit tables of the entities that you want to track, when you are doing any operation from the JDBC i.e. save/update/delete you fire another jdbc statement as well which insert a row in the audit table where you can store all the necessary information i.e.. user who modified what, operation type etc. I would also suggest to look for audit trail based framework for jdbc.

Comment: Have you considered enabling/inspecting the [general query log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/query-log.html)? "*The general query log is a general record of what mysqld is doing. The server writes information to this log when clients connect or disconnect, and it logs each SQL statement received from clients. The general query log can be very useful when you suspect an error in a client and want to know exactly what the client sent to mysqld.*" Of course, it's only really intended for debugging: if you want to maintain an audit log, you should really handle that at the application level.

Comment: I did create a audit log for this and use triggers to store the information in it, thought @BilboBaggins idea is also plausible but I would need to change a lot in my code for this, is there anyway to do this using triggers instead?

Comment: Triggers run at the database level and are not well suited to audit logging, since they do not run within the application context (which often contains additional information one wishes to record in the log).

Comment: I would suggest to keep the concern out of the code as well, i.e. write something like aspect, which can help in minimal modification in existing code, however you might have to write some code using some pattern i.e. Observer pattern or write some listeners or some filters, to log/audit your required entities.

Comment: @BilboBaggins I'm sorry but I'm really not that familiar with those terms, forgive my ignorance on this. though I might just stick to using triggers and  instead add a new field in my table called "changer" and use that value in my trigger so that I can keep track of the changes made by "changer"

Comment: Well you can take it as new learning, those are merely words with very simple explanation behind them, however if the time constraint is there, then I would not suggest to make changes in code, stick to what you have :), take the changes to next iteration of release ;)